# How do I fill a data grid with a string array?

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, datagrid

**How do I fill a data grid with a string array in C# (WPF)?**

I have a string array: `string[] pdfFiles;` and I have made the following configurations as well: `AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}"`. Unfortunately, it only fills my data grid with blank lines. I fill it that way: `dataGrid.ItemsSource = pdfFiles;`.

**EDIT:** Here is my XAML code:

```
<DataGrid Height="287" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="181,12,0,0" Name="dataGrid" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="310" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
```

Comment: post the XAML code, did you defined the column

Comment: First, its better change string[] to Collection<string>. Second I dont know how you set datacontext. In my opinion: userconotrl.datacontext = viewmodel. Then in datagrid ItemSource="{Binding pdfFiles}" from Property of viewmodel. And dont forget set fieldname for column.

Comment: XAML code added. I did not set a "data context" - is that my fault?

Comment: Yes if you are binding, you have to set datacontext to usercontrol or to datagrid. Here is example [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/321899/DataContext-in-WPF)

Comment: Okay, thanks. But what do you mean by "usercontrol or datagrid" - I don't get it. :/

Comment: AutoGenerateColumns="False" with no columns given ain't going to work I'm afraid. Add up a column with {Binding} (you are right no more need  to be done with binding) - but a column is required, otherwise use AutoGenerateColumns="True".

Comment: When you are creating xaml, DataGrid can be included to UserControl or other visual elements. You can set DataContext to root - UserControl for all elements, or only for DataGrid. I think every visual elements has property DataContext. See MSDN documentation.

Comment: you are pointing the items source to the list of strings which is fine but as explained above you need a column called like string to which is bound to the string contained in the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here I make example which is works.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding PdfFiles}"></DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<string> PdfFiles { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        PdfFiles = new List<string>();
        PdfFiles.Add("a");
        PdfFiles.Add("aa");
        PdfFiles.Add("aaa");
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
 <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding PdfFiles}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks, that sounds good. But unfortunately, I have the same problem here as mentioned above: There is no content in the lines - there is only a blank box and the length of the string.

Comment: I customized it to my declarations, but YES.

Comment: Ok, I modified example see, above.

Comment: It's working too with array. But You can use System.Linq and extension ToList(). Or constructor new List<string>(pdfFiles).

Comment: I've got it. Google is my friend ;) Now I just need to delete the LENGTH which is automatically generated.

Comment: Only add to datagridtextcolumn property:  Header="YOUR HEADER NAME"
If working, please, mark as answer. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I did that. But nevertheless, the LENGTH is generated.

Comment: Did you try this?
 `<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}" Header="test" />`

Comment: Yes --> <DataGridTextColumn Header="Dateiname" Binding="{Binding}" />

Comment: It has to works. I dont know why is not working. I have the same Header and after run I see Dateiname. Did you add any properties to DataGrid?

Comment: Yes, I did. Look at this: <DataGrid Height="150" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="12,41,12,70" Name="dataGrid" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="454" ItemsSource="{Binding pdfFiles}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" BorderBrush="Silver" HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Gainsboro" VerticalGridLinesBrush="Gainsboro" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False">

Comment: Additional information: I read strings from a open file dialog. Maybe it's important...

Comment: Set the AutoGenerateColumns to False.

Comment: Best man in town! ;) Thank you very much. Complete problem is solved. ~ closed.